# how to programmatically set label frame.ref_time in wireshark capture

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I have hundreds of capture files and need to summarise the responses to a specific request that the server issues to a large number of clients. I am using scripts to process capture files using tshark.

I want to programmatically set `frame.ref_time` for packets matching a certain display filter and then rescan using `frame.time_relative < x seconds` to suit my purpose (I am already using `tcp.stream` as a filter but need to restrict further).

Neither tshark nor editcap seem to do this but I'm not sure. Surely this ability is not restricted to the gui?

How can I set `frame.ref_time` programmatically from a script?
Having set the label, is there a blunt way to clear all labels, or should I be elegant and perform the reverse operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can only set `frame.ref_time` using the GUI; however, this limitation might not necessarily be a problem for you.  Once you apply a filter, then all frames become frame-relative to the first packet matching the filter when those packets are written to a new file **or** piped to another `tshark` instance; therefore you should be able to achieve what you need using two instances of `tshark`, the first one to isolate the stream of interest and the 2nd one to isolate those frames matching the time-relative criteria.

For example, suppose you're interested in packets associated with *TCP stream 0*, but only those packets that are part of that stream which were received within 0.1 seconds following the start of the stream.  In that case you could use a command such as:

```
tshark -r capturefile.pcap -Y "tcp stream eq 0" -w - | tshark -r - -Y "frame.time_relative < 0.1"
```

Refer to the [tshark man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information on `tshark` options.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I end up with the two relevant frames per stream that I need without extra clutter. It is much faster than my previous solution (which had not finished running) despite calling tshark an extra time.